# JQGrid remove value from custom error message

Tags: jqgrid

In inline navigation, i want to remove user entered value from custom error message.
So far all examples have this sticked to message.

For e.g. I want to remove date "2013-blah blah"

[image]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/579/1044002386.png))</sub>

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: I used same way for custom validation functio ... editrules:{custom: true, custom_func: customValidationMessage}, but it does not work for inline editing

Comment: This jsfiddle shows the problem. jsfiddle.net/philcruz/44ZQ2

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom_func to achieve this.

Add editrules to column details in colModel like given below

```
editrules:{custom: true, custom_func: customValidationMessage}
```

and the  function (In this case I am doing validation for required, you can do your validation for date in if condition )

```
function customValidationMessage(val, colname) {
        if (val.trim() == "") {
        return [ false,colname + " is required " ];
        } else {
        return [ true, "" ];
        }
          }
```

Comment: This does not work for inline edits. work only in add/edit dialog.